# Prevent custom generator from generating tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, thor

I am learning to write generators. I used Rails' scaffold_controller generator as the starting point.

```
require 'rails/generators/resource_helpers'
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldControllerGenerator < NamedBase # :nodoc:
      include ResourceHelpers

      check_class_collision suffix: "Controller"

      class_option :helper, type: :boolean
      class_option :orm, banner: "NAME", type: :string, required: true,
                         desc: "ORM to generate the controller for"

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      def create_controller_files
        template "controller.rb", File.join('app/controllers', controller_class_path, "#{controller_file_name}_controller.rb")
      end

      #hook_for :template_engine, :test_framework, as: :scaffold
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, I commented out the `hook_for`, hoping this will not hook up the test framework generators. However when I run this generator, tests are still generated. Plus, I also want to skip jbuilder and helper generation. Here is a list of all things generated:

```
  create  app/controllers/books_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/books
  create    app/views/books/index.html.erb
  create    app/views/books/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/books/show.html.erb
  create    app/views/books/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/books/_form.html.erb
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/books_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  invoke  jbuilder
  create    app/views/books/index.json.jbuilder
  create    app/views/books/show.json.jbuilder
```

How can I skil generating test/helper/jbuilder by configuring my custom generator?

Comment: You sure it's using your generator? Print out some debug statements in `create_controller_files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was actually monkey patching the same generator class, so the original setting will still be intact.

I have to remove these hooks manually.

```
      remove_hook_for :jbuilder, :test_framework
```